# How to block communication from specific Bluetooth hardware address(es)

Tags: bluetooth

Would like to know how a Bluetooth application can in general block communications initiated from "identified intruders" based on the Bluetooth hardware address?

Comment: what platform would this be on?

Answer (score 0):

Some platforms allow you to Black list devices, this will be a good way to block identified intruders.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more clarity into it if possible by means of an example?

Comment: which platform / OS are you trying to do this on ?

Comment: I am in the design phase of an adapter. I am planning to select a bluetooth module with in-built stack in it, and would have a micro controller program has to access this stack and block if possible. So my question is, in normally available embedded BT stacks, have you come across options which helps us to block the intruders?

Comment: yes I have seen and worked with few embedded bluetooth stacks that offer few mechanisms - like ability to set list of trusted or non-trusted devices , also ability for application to be notified of incoming connection and ask application to authorize connection - this would enable application to maintain the list of devices to block and block them. (If these help and has answered you original question please vote the answer and also accept it)